# Carry Ripple Adder - VHDL

Tags: vhdl

How can I connect Full Adders together to form a Carry Ripple Adder?
Here is what I have so far.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity CarryRippleAdder is
    Port ( Carry_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
           input_A : in  STD_LOGIC;
           input_B : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Carry_out : out  STD_LOGIC);
end CarryRippleAdder;

architecture Behavioral of CarryRippleAdder is

-- FullAdder
COMPONENT FullAdder
PORT(
    A_in : IN std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    B_in : IN std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    C_in: IN std_logic;
    C_out : out  std_logic;
    S_out : out  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;

begin
 -- FullAdder0
    FA0: Fuller PORT MAP(
              C_in => Carry_in
              A_in 
       B_in
       C_out 
          S_out
);

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: You appear to have the port maps reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to use a whole bunch of one-bit adders to create (what looks like) a 16 bit adder.

So your top level entity should have 16 bit signal inputs and outputs, and you should instantiate the 1-bit adder. Here's an example image showing 4 bits of adder:

[image: pic]

In the case of the above, your inputs to your entity should be

```
A    : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
B    : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
C_in : in std_logic;
```

and the output should be

```
S     : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
C_out : out std_logic;
```

Instantiate the one bit adder, connect as in diagram for as many bits as you need, and you're done.